# Can't get XmlDocument.SelectNodes to retrieve value?

Tags: xml, nodes

**XML Document:**

```
<HotelValuedAvailRS xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages HotelValuedAvailRS.xsd" timeToExpiration="1799971" totalItems="90" echoToken="DummyEchoToken"><AuditData><ProcessTime>275</ProcessTime><Timestamp>2014-11-04 11:39:28.253</Timestamp><RequestHost>54.169.51.224</RequestHost><ServerName>FORM</ServerName><ServerId>FO</ServerId><SchemaRelease>2005/06</SchemaRelease><HydraCoreRelease>2014.07.10.PCI</HydraCoreRelease><HydraEnumerationsRelease>N/A</HydraEnumerationsRelease><MerlinRelease>N/A</MerlinRelease></AuditData><PaginationData currentPage="1" totalPages="5"/><ServiceHotel xsi:type="ServiceHotel" availToken="18S4Jo2aVQeZLWqDTnJ3bwbh"><ContractList><Contract><Name>ID_B2B_24#BARI</Name><IncomingOffice code="1"></IncomingOffice><Classification code="NOR">Online Price</Classification></Contract></ContractList><DateFrom date="20141228"/><DateTo date="20141230"/><Currency code="EUR">Euro</Currency><HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel"><Code>271</Code><Name>TRYP Palma Bellver Hotel</Name><ImageList><Image><Type>jpg</Type><Order>1</Order><VisualizationOrder>1</VisualizationOrder><Url>http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/000271/000271a_hb_a_003.jpg</Url></Image><Image><Type>jpg</Type><Order>2</Order><VisualizationOrder>2</VisualizationOrder><Url>http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/00/000271/000271a_hb_w_001.jpg</Url></Image></ImageList><Category type="SIMPLE" code="4EST" shortname="4*">4 STARS</Category><Destination type="SIMPLE" code="PMI"><Name>Majorca</Name><ZoneList><Zone type="SIMPLE" code="10">Palma</Zone></ZoneList></Destination><ChildAge ageFrom="0" ageTo="0"/><Position latitude="39.56860999999999961574" longitude="2.63178000000000000824"/></HotelInfo><AvailableRoom><HotelOccupancy><RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy><HotelRoom SHRUI="F7TSfb7tBLYH3W4X5CaNVA==" availCount="99" onRequest="N"><Board type="SIMPLE" code="SH-E10" shortname="RO">ROOM ONLY</Board><RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="ST">DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomType><Price><Amount>149.740</Amount></Price></HotelRoom></AvailableRoom><AvailableRoom><HotelOccupancy><RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy><HotelRoom SHRUI="7zsBOMYAObs09Gt/WwvZIg==" availCount="99" onRequest="N"><Board type="SIMPLE" code="HD-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board><RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="ST">DOUBLE STANDARD</RoomType><Price><Amount>190.120</Amount></Price></HotelRoom></AvailableRoom><AvailableRoom><HotelOccupancy><RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy><HotelRoom SHRUI="HMrRj2pAKzao/Y1tnmr20A==" availCount="99" onRequest="N"><Board type="SIMPLE" code="SH-E10" shortname="RO">ROOM ONLY</Board><RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="VM">DOUBLE SEA VIEW</RoomType><Price><Amount>203.580</Amount></Price></HotelRoom></AvailableRoom><AvailableRoom><HotelOccupancy><RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy><HotelRoom SHRUI="1+9/i90A0ZqbOmZlDSFStw==" availCount="99" onRequest="N"><Board type="SIMPLE" code="HD-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board><RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="DBL-E10" characteristic="VM">DOUBLE SEA VIEW</RoomType><Price><Amount>243.960</Amount></Price></HotelRoom></AvailableRoom><AvailableRoom><HotelOccupancy><RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy><HotelRoom SHRUI="sLrp9E+6lq/FBOsvMhv7Qw==" availCount="99" onRequest="N"><Board type="SIMPLE" code="SH-E10" shortname="RO">ROOM ONLY</Board><RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="JSU-E10" characteristic="ST">JUNIOR SUITE STANDARD</RoomType><Price><Amount>358.370</Amount></Price></HotelRoom></AvailableRoom><AvailableRoom><HotelOccupancy><RoomCount>1</RoomCount><Occupancy><AdultCount>2</AdultCount><ChildCount>0</ChildCount></Occupancy></HotelOccupancy><HotelRoom SHRUI="KiWIO7156n0+4HmG3UiKrw==" availCount="99" onRequest="N"><Board type="SIMPLE" code="HD-E10" shortname="BB">BED AND BREAKFAST</Board><RoomType type="SIMPLE" code="JSU-E10" characteristic="ST">JUNIOR SUITE STANDARD</RoomType><Price><Amount>398.750</Amount></Price></HotelRoom></AvailableRoom></ServiceHotel></HotelValuedAvailRS>
```

**C# Code:**

```
XmlDocument xdcDocument = new XmlDocument();

xdcDocument.Load(@"E:\\Hotel.xml");

XmlElement xelRoot = xdcDocument.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList listOfContacts = xdcDocument.SelectNodes("/HotelValuedAvailRS/ServiceHotel/HotelInfo");
foreach (XmlNode xndNode in listOfContacts)
{
    string name = xndNode["Name"].InnerText;
    string order = xndNode["Order"].InnerText;
}
```

I am not getting any details from the XML above with the above code. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The xpath you're using to select `listOfContacts` doesn't match what's in the document. Change it to specify the actual path of the nodes you're interested in.

Actually, neither do the element names inside the loop. What nodes from the document were you expecting those to match?

edit #1: In actual fact, now you've specified the whole document, this makes more sense. I had to compile and run this myself but it turns out you're missing a namespace declaration in the xpath. You've declared the root element to be in the namespace http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/2005/06/messages but the xpath you have only selects elements in no namespace.

The easiest way to solve this is to use a prefix in front of every element name in the xpath:

`"/ns:HotelValuedAvailRS/ns:ServiceHotel/ns:HotelInfo"`

And pass an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) with this prefix defined to the call to `SelectNodes`.

Comment: Hi tom. I could not pass whole XML document here. Actually my path is correct. Please check the updated XML document.

Comment: Hi tom. Thanks a lot. This was really help. But I need to ask one more thing here. I am having "<HotelInfo>" node which contain hotel name info. There is another node call "<ImageList>" which contains aging sub node call "<Image>". I want to loop through "<ImageList>" node and get all the details come under "<Image>" node. I need to loop below XML part.<HotelInfo xsi:type="ProductHotel<Name>TRYP Palma Bellver Hotel</Name><ImageList><Image><Type>jpg</Type></Image><Image><Type>png</Type></Image></ImageList></ HotelInfo> Please help me to get details of imagenode

Comment: The task is almost precisely the same as the one you're already doing, only varying the path required to select the set of Image nodes. You really don't need my help to do that.